# Proving Hilbert Cube is Complete

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Before anything I would like to say that yes, I have seen the other proofs of this on here, and yes I have given them a thorough attempt, but I am still not fully understanding them to be able write it out in confidence.

> The Hilbert Cube, $(H^\infty,d)$ , is a collection of all real sequences $x = \{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ with $\vert x_n \vert \leq 1$ for $n=1,2,\ldots$ and $d(x,y)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n}\vert x_n-y_n \vert$.
>
> Let $A=\{x^{(1)},x^{(2)},\ldots\}$ be a sequence in $H^{\infty}$, such that $x^{(k)}= x^{(k)}_1,x^{(k)}_2,\ldots$. Now, given this representation, we consider the sequence of first coordinates, which is a subsequence of $A$. Thus, we have $\{x^{(1)}_1,x^{(2)}_1,x^{(3)}_1,\ldots\}$. Suppose we consider the sequence of the second coordinates, which is a subsequence of $A$, $\{x^{(1)}_2,x^{(2)}_2,x^{(3)}_2,\ldots\}$. Thus, we can can iterate this process for each "coordinate", then

This is the point where I am confused as what to do.  My initial thought its to 'stack' these coordinate sequences and take the diagonal of them, but this does not feel right since this does not necessary guarantee that it is going to converge.

Any suggestions or clarifications of other proofs on here would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you defining the Hilbert cube as $[0,1]^\mathbb{N}$ in the product topology? (And how then do you define that? Via a metric or the standard base?), or as some subspace of $\ell_2$? Please specify.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I just added what metric I am assumed to use.

Comment: Can you use complete + totally bounded? And do you know $H^\infty$ is complete?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I know how to do the totally bounded, but showing it is complete is my issue.

Comment: Completeness is quite easy: given the Cauchy sequence $(x_n)$ in $H^\infty$, prove first that for each $k$ the coordinatewise sequence $(x_n^{(k)})_n$ is also Cauchy in $[-1,1]$ as $ |x_m^{(k)} -x_n^{(k)}| \le 2^k d(x_n, x_m)$, and the right hand term can be made as small as we like, for big enough $n,m$. Then $[-1,1]$ is complete so this sequence has a limit $p_k \in [-1,1]$. This defines a point $p = (p_1 ,p_2, \ldots)$ Now do some manipulation with some series to show that $d(x_n, p) \to 0$, so that $x_n \to p$ and we have completeness.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's compact and the simplest way to prove it is compact is to use the theorem that a product of compact spaces is compact.

Comment: This is very nice and succint, but I am unable to use this theorem since this is not a theorem I have proved, or covered in my topology course (yet), which is why I am attempting to use a diagonal argument.

Comment: Is this really that simple? Can you do it with a much easier version of the full-strength Tychonoff's theorem? Or are the other ways just so much worse?

Comment: The OP is considering the Hilbert cube as a special subspace of $\ell_2$, possibly.

Comment: So it doesn't have a standard product structure.